# Integral over hemiellipsoid

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, volume

I have to solve the the following integral
$\int_{D}^{} A \cdot dS$, where $D$ is the surface of the hemiellipsoid $(\frac{x}{a})^2+ (\frac{y}{b})^2 + (\frac{z}{c})^2= 1$ a,b and c are known. It is also given from the task that $A$ can be written as $A=(B \cdot r)C$, where $B$ and $C$ are constant vectors, and $r$ is the position vector. From what I see, it seems easiest to use Gauss law for integration, where we instead of integrating over the surface of the hemiellipsoid, we integrate over the volume. However, I don't seem to know what to do with the expression $\nabla \cdot A = \nabla \cdot ((B \cdot r)C)$.

EDIT

I've tried to expand the expression above to $\nabla \cdot A = \nabla \cdot ((B \cdot r)C)= \nabla \cdot (BC \cdot rC)= (\nabla \cdot BC)\cdot rC = 0$, since $BC$ is a constant vector, which should mean that the divergence is 0. But that means that the entire integral will be $0$, which seems odd.

Comment: What you've written is nonsense, I'm afraid. There's no multiplication of vectors and no such associative law. If nothing else, write everything out in components and compute the divergence in $x,y,z$ coordinates. The answer will be quite simple. However, when you use Gauss's Law, make sure you close up the surface by putting in the bottom and computing that flux as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ted Shifrin noted, your expression for the divergence of A is incorrect. Resolving it into components,
$$r=\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}\\A=(B_xx+B_yy+B_zz)\begin{bmatrix}C_x\\C_y\\C_z\end{bmatrix}\\\nabla\cdot{A}=C_xB_x+C_yB_y+C_zB_z=C\cdot{B}$$ Thus,
$$\int_DA\cdot{dS}=C\cdot{B}\iiint_VdV$$
Using the formula for the volume of an ellipse and dividing by two, you get:
$$\int_DA\cdot{dS}=C\cdot{B}\frac4 6\pi{abc}$$

Comment: Yeah, I totally see my errors. Resolving into components seems so much easier to understand and makes much more sense. Thank you so much for explaining this.

Comment: I have this case of needing to compute the flux of the hemiellipsoid, since it is not closed. I know the formula for it, which is the integral over the bottom disk of the hemiellipsoid when z=0 of the vector field A, but whan I seem to struggle with is that I don't know what steps to take.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to fiddling with components, use the [dyadic product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadics#Product_of_dyadic_and_vector).
$$\eqalign{
A &= (CB)\cdot r \\
dA &= (CB)\cdot dr \quad&\big({\rm differential}\big) \\
\nabla A &= CB \quad&\big({\rm gradient}\big) \\
\nabla\cdot A &= C\cdot B \quad&\big({\rm divergence}\big) \\
}$$
Then apply the [divergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem#Mathematical_statement) over the hemi-ellipsoidal region $\Omega$.
$$\eqalign{
\oint_{\partial\Omega}A\cdot dS
 &= \int_\Omega\left(\nabla\cdot A\right)\;dV \\
 &= \int_\Omega(C\cdot B)\;dV \\
 &= (C\cdot B)\int_\Omega dV \\
 &= (C\cdot B)\left(\frac{2\pi abc}{3}\right) \\
}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Your explanation made it very clear to me of what was going!