# Calculating the flux over the base of a hemiellipsoid

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, volume, surface-integrals

I have this task where I'm supposed to calculate $\int_{D}((\textbf{B} \cdot \textbf{r})\textbf{C})d\textbf{S}$, where $D$ is hemiellipsoid $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2} = 1, z>0$. I know that I can rewrite this with help of Gauss theorem, which gives me $$\int_{D}((\textbf{B} \cdot \textbf{r})\textbf{C})d\textbf{S} + \int_{D'}((\textbf{B} \cdot \textbf{r})\textbf{C})d\textbf{S} = \int_{V}\nabla \cdot((\textbf{B} \cdot \textbf{r})\textbf{C})d\textbf{V}.$$ The vectors $C$ and $B$ are constant vectors and $r$ is the position vector. $D'$ is the bottom plate of the hemiellipsoid when z=0. I've calculated this to be $2\pi abc/3+\int_{D'}((\textbf{B} \cdot \textbf{r})\textbf{C})d\textbf{S}$. But I don't seem to understand how I'm supposed to get the second integral with D' because of the vector I'm supposed to integrate.

Comment: Your question looks identical to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3850506)

Comment: It is, but with one exception. This one lacks a bottom plate. It is the second derivative that needs to be calculated here, which I am facing difficulties with.

Comment: The hemi-ellipsiod is a _closed_ surface, so the bottom plate has already been taken into account by the divergence theorem. The integral over $D'$ needs to be dropped from the RHS.

Comment: Yeah, this is the one that I need to calculate since I already have the integral over the closed surface. In my case, the hemi-ellipsoid isn't closed. The integral over D' that needs to be dropped off is the one that I have trouble with. So far, I've said that a perpendicular vector to the bottom plate is n=(0,0,-1). This leaves me with the integral over D'  of -Cz(B*r), where Cz is the z-component of the constant vector C. I feel like there should be a more efficient way of calculating this integral.